# How this formula is deriving 2^N + 2^N = 2^(N+1)

Tags: math, data-structures, exponent

If the bases are same and variables are adding , then it becomes like this

```
^ represent power
X^N + X^N = 2X^N not X^2N
```

like we take common

```
X^N(1 + 1) = 2X^N
```

but in the case `2^N + 2^N = 2^(N+1)`

if we take common

```
2^N(1 + 1) = (2)2^N
```

How it is becoming

```
2^(N+1)
```

I read this formula in a book ***Data Structures and algorithm analysis in Java 3rd edition***. I am confuse.

Thanks

Comment: That is basic algebra.  `2*(2^4) = 2*(2*2*2*2) = 2*2*2*2*2 = 2^5`

Comment: this is complexity notation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2n + 2n` is equal to `2n * 2` or `2n * 21`.

That's equivalent to `2n+1` because `xm * xn = xm+n` (see note 1 below).

---

<sup>(note 1)</sup> As to *why* this is the case, you can see the reason here:

`x2 * x3

= (x * x) * (x * x * x)

= x * x * x * x * x

= x5`

Answer (score 2):

Here the rule for multiplication of powers is applied

```
X^N * X^N = X^(N+N)
```

So if we take your example now

```
2^N + 2^N = 2*(2^N) = 2^1 * 2^N = 2^(1+N) = 2^(N+1)
```

With extra steps for clarity

Comment: Ah yes in the last step, rule for multiplication of powers is applying, so simple ..... First bases are same but adding and then bases are same and multiplying ... thanks